# Rails One-To-Many Nested Form. No Image displayed in browser when using show action controller? (Paperclip Gem used)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paperclip

I'm trying to create a posting form to post a url & image. The nested form submits without an error but I can't display the subsequent image of that form in the browser. I have used the paperclip gem for the image upload.

Post Model

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :urls 
   has_many :photos 
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :urls, :photos
  end
```

Url Model

```
   class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
   end
```

Photo Model

```
   class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :post 

     has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100>" }
     validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
 end
```

Posts Controller

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @urls = @post.urls 
   @photos = @post.photos 
  end 

  def new
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

 def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params) 
   if @post.save 
     redirect_to @post
   else 
     render 'new'
  end 
 end

     private 
     def post_params 
    params.require(:post).permit(:image, :urls_attributes => [:urlattr])
   end 
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
 <% @urls.each do |url| %>
 <%= url.urlattr %>
 <% end %>

 <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
 <%= image_tag photo.image.url(:large) %>
 <% end %>
```

Database Schema

```
 create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.string   "image_file_name"
  t.string   "image_content_type"
  t.integer  "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  t.integer  "post_id"
 end

 add_index "photos", ["post_id"], name: "index_photos_on_post_id"

 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 create_table "urls", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "urlattr"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "post_id"
 end

add_index "urls", ["post_id"], name: "index_urls_on_post_id"

end
```

Page displayed after using the form to post a URL (type www.example.com into form) & Image (not showing up in browser) ![]http://imgur.com/ct0TjHQ

Your help would be amazing - thank you!

Comment: Did you check if the resource is being actually saved? (the db record and actual image file)? 
Have you used the browser inspector to see the url being generated for the image?

Comment: @FabianoArruda - in the rails console Photo.count was an empty array [] after posting. I used the browser inspector on the form itself - after uploading a photo, nothing changed. Also, no url for the image showed up in the inspector in the show view page either after posting :/